# Configurar Slim Framework e Apache 2

Tags: php, linux, htaccess, restful, slim

Olá, boa tarde.

Recentemente contratei uma hospedagem linux. 
Meu site usa o Slim Framework, mas não estou conseguindo acessar as rotas dele quando está em produção, mas no localhost xampp, estava funcionando normalmente.

Rotas do Slim pra teste (não esta entrando em nenhuma)

```
$app->group("/teste", function() {
    $this->get("/", function(Request $request, Response $response, $args = []) {
        return $response->write("deu");
    });

    $this->get("/:nome", function(Request $request, Response $response, $args = []) {
        return $response->write("deu ".$args['nome']);
    });
});
```

**A minha dúvida é se o .htaccess está correto.**

Localizado em public_html/slim/biblioteca/

Aqui se encontra o index.php (do slim) e o arquivo .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L]
```

testei diferentes códigos .htaccess as vezes dava erro 404 e outras o erro 500. Atualmente como código acima, da o erro 500.

**E se é necessário criar um arquivo httpd.conf e habilitar AllowOverride All. E como eu posso fazer isso?**

Podem ver na imagem com o diretório do projeto, a pasta /etc/ apenas possui 2 arquivos e uma subpasta com o nome do site, que está vazia também.

Alguém poderia me ajudar?

http://oi67.tinypic.com/2aak775.jpg

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Se o problema for com o URL Rewrite você pode tentar usar assim: `index.php/teste`, por exemplo. Foi o que eu fiz.

Comment: @NotTheRealHemingway oi, onde eu deveria colocar index.php/teste?

Comment: Dá uma olhada na minha resposta.

Answer (score 1):

Primeiro:

Você pode usar as rotas [sem URL Rewrite](http://docs.slimframework.com/routing/rewrite/#without-url-rewriting).

De acordo com a documentação, você pode acessar assim:

```html
<?php
$app = new \Slim\Slim();
$app->get('/index.php/foo', function () {
    echo "Foo!";
});
$app->run();
```

Se o arquivo da rota estiver dentro de uma pasta chamada ***blog***:

```html
<?php
$app = new \Slim\Slim();
$app->get('/blog/index.php/foo', function () {
    echo "Foo!";
});
$app->run();
```

Entretanto, a equipe que desenvolveu o micro framework encoraja o uso do mod rewrite. Dessa forma, o **.htaccess** deve estar na [mesma pasta](http://docs.slimframework.com/routing/rewrite/) que **index.php**:

```html
/path/www.mysite.com/
    public_html/ <-- Document root!
        .htaccess
        index.php <-- I instantiate Slim here!
    lib/
        Slim/ <-- I store Slim lib files here!
```

O seu código está certo de acordo com as especificações da documentação (é o mesmo!).

No entanto, aqui está outro exemplo de acordo com o tutorial "[*First Application Walkthrough*](https://www.slimframework.com/docs/tutorial/first-app.html)":

```html
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

Se o ero surge com o PHP 5.5.*, então, [a solução pode ser descomentar a seguinte linha em **httpd.conf**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30143702/slim-framework-500-internal-server-error):

```
LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
```

A solução ainda pode estar em adicionar

```
RewriteBase /raizdosite/
```

ao seu projeto.

Você também pode procurar no log do Apache pela causa do erro.

Comment: o .htaccess e o index.php estao na mesma pasta. Esse código que passou eu ja testei tb deu a mesma coisa.

Comment: Eu não consigo visualizar sua imagem. O *imgur* tá bloqueado no meu trabalho.

Comment: Tentei usar /index.php/teste/ no slim ... Por exemplo a url meusite.com.br/teste/ , não deu tb.

Comment: http://oi67.tinypic.com/2aak775.jpg tenta nesse link. No caso é pra mostrar que nao tem arquivo httpd.conf, se for preciso criar um e habilitar o AllowOverride All.

Comment: Tira a barra depois de `/index.php/teste/`. Use somente `/index.php/teste`. Eu vou conseguir elaborar melhor somente quando chegar em casa à noite. Desculpa!